Which is fastest way to fetch large data's from database in spring boot Application
I'm currently working on spring boot project. In my project i am using criteria builder for fetch data from postgres database its work fine for smaller data. But didn't work for larger data.so I decided to move to an other options
( JPQL, jdbc template). Could you give suggestions which is fastest way to fetch data in spring boot
( **JPQL, jdbc template, raw query **). Could you give suggestions which is fastest way to fetch data in spring boot

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Here are the best approaches for handling large datasets in Spring Boot, ordered by performance:

JdbcTemplate (Fastest)

Provides the best performance as it's closest to the database
Allows direct control over fetch size and connection parameters
Best for very large datasets (millions of records)
No entity mapping overhead
Drawback: Manual mapping required


Native Queries with Streaming

Nearly as fast as JdbcTemplate
Allows SQL optimization specific to your database
Supports cursor-based fetching
Good balance between performance and convenience


JPQL with Streaming

Decent performance for large datasets
More maintainable than raw SQL
Database-agnostic
Supports lazy loading
Slightly slower than native queries due to mapping overhead


Pagination

Good for presenting data to users
Consistent memory usage
Works well with REST APIs
Can be slower for processing entire datasets as it requires multiple queries



Key recommendations for optimizing large data fetches:

Set appropriate fetch size (typically 100-1000)
Use read-only transactions when possible
Stream results rather than loading everything into memory
Consider pagination for user-facing operations
Use proper indexes on your database
Select only required columns rather than fetching entire entities

Some code examples
// 1. Using JdbcTemplate with Stream
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    public void processLargeData() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = true";
        
        jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(1000); // Set appropriate fetch size
        jdbcTemplate.query(
            sql,
            resultSet -> {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    // Process each row here
                    User user = User.builder()
                        .id(resultSet.getLong("id"))
                        .name(resultSet.getString("name"))
                        .build();
                    processUser(user);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}

// 2. Using JPA/JPQL with Streaming
@Service
public class UserJpaService {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void streamUsers() {
        String jpql = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.active = true";
        
        try (Stream<User> userStream = entityManager.createQuery(jpql, User.class)
                .setHint(QueryHints.FETCH_SIZE, 1000)
                .getResultStream()) {
            
            userStream.forEach(this::processUser);
        }
    }
}

// 3. Using Native Query with Cursor
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = true", 
           nativeQuery = true)
    @QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name = JDBC_FETCH_SIZE, value = "1000"),
        @QueryHint(name = READ_ONLY, value = "true")
    })
    Stream<User> streamAllUsersWithCursor();
}

// 4. Using Pagination
@Service
public class UserPaginationService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public void processUsersInBatches() {
        int pageSize = 1000;
        int pageNumber = 0;
        Page<User> userPage;
        
        do {
            userPage = userRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize));
            processUserBatch(userPage.getContent());
            pageNumber++;
        } while (userPage.hasNext());
    }
}

